# appending query string in form action

Tags: jquery, html, forms, encoding

My question might seems odd, but I am caught in situation..

Can I use form action in this way??

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/cread.php?inmid=5445&affid=545&p=http://www.book.example2.com/search.do" method="get" id="form1">
```

what I am trying to do is

- User will fill the form
- data along with a inmid, affid and p will be passed to
  example.com/cread.php
- example.com/cread.php will process
- example.com then will forward the form data to p=example2.com/search.do
- example2.com/search.do will do the rest...

I tried using `inmid, affid` and `p` as hidden inputs,but due to url encoding issue, example.com/search.do can not process the form data..

this form action isn't working for me..

can somebody tell me how can I achieve my purpose??

thnks for any help

**PS**

- I DONT have control over `example.com` or `example2.com`
- If I use tracking params as hidden, Url encoding and decoding ( which
  I cant control) create problem...however, If I use the form action
  with partial query string alongwith form data, it works

Comment: Better use a clean action like `action="http://www.example.com/cread.php` and put the values on input type hidden....

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden inputs instead of starting the query string yourself.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" value="value goes here" />
```

I think the reason what you have isn't working is because you've started the query string yourself with a `?`and then you've added your values. However, once the form is submitted, another `?` and all the form data is going to be appended to whatever you have in the `action` attribute.

So effectively, the query string would be started twice, as there would be two `?`'s which may not be able to be interpreted by the server correctly.

The query string generated would be: eg: `formSubmit.php?IAddedThis=true?IWasAddedByTheBrowser=true`

I'm open to correction though.